# Cross Platform Screenshot and screen Resolution

Tags: qt, boost, screenshot, resolution

I need to take screenshot, get the current screen resolution, and the list of supported resolutions. Currently I am having System Specific Wrappers on these three, Is there any cross platform light weight library that can do the same ? I also need mouse/keyboard Event Abstraction That I am doing by Qt's Event now. is there any even better option for that too ?

Answer (score 1):

In Qt you have QDesktopWidget to access desktop information (available size, screen geometry). To grab sreenshot check Qt's [screenshot example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-screenshot.html)